# Upload file using jsf 2, jpa 2 to a system directory without using tomahwak, or primefaces

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jpa, ejb-3.0, glassfish-4

I'm using glassfish 4.0, eclipse,I want to upload file to an xhtml page then show them in another xhtml using only jsf2 jpa2 and ejb 3 without any libraries such as tomahwak or primefaces ... Also files should be stored in a system folder, and the file's relative information in database
thanks

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: OK, my question is how to copy the uploaded file from the temporary directory of glassfish 4 server to a system directory and store the paths to this file.